# What genre is Jackson and His Computerband - "Blood Bust"?

Tags: identify-this-genre

[Jackson and His Computerband - Blood Bust (brainwashing video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0SGmRsxF7g)

What genre is this?  It's too fast for Downtempo.  You can't call it Drum and Bass. I think it's too slow for Hardtechno.

I am trying to find something similar to it, but I'm failing badly.

Answer (score 2):

This track seems to be in the genre ["French Touch" or "French House"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_house). Quoting from Wikipedia:

> The defining characteristics of the sound are heavy reliance on filter and phaser effects both on and alongside samples from late 1970s and early 1980s American or European disco tracks. . .

This seems like an accurate description of *Blood Bust*: the heavy filters and phaser effects are the defining aspects of this track for me.

[This review](https://consequenceofsound.net/2013/09/album-review-jackson-and-his-computer-band-glow/) at [Consequence of Sound (Cos)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequence_of_Sound) also says that *Blood Bust* is in the genre French House.

---

Although I am not very familiar with this type of music, it appears that [Jackson Fourgeaud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_and_His_Computerband) seems to be known for some eccentric compositions, combining different genres together in ways that defy simple characterisation. Here's an extract from a [review on Clash Music](https://www.clashmusic.com/reviews/jackson-and-his-computerband-glow) of the album [*Glow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_(Jackson_and_His_Computerband_album)) (which contains the track *Blood Bust*):

> There’s the synthpop aspect, sure, but we also take in house, techno, rock and even the more hypnagogic elements of the hyper-modern shopping mall that is vaporave. Vocals pinball around the tracks, sometimes treated with the harshest of electronic effects.

For instance, [Metacritic](https://www.metacritic.com/music/glow/jackson-and-his-computerband) labels the album genres as Electronic, Experimental, Electronica, Pop/Rock. Wikipedia lists the genres that Jackson works in as Electro House, Electronic Rock, French Touch.